# How to send SQS message to FIFO type Queue

Tags: c#, amazon-sqs

I can easily send and receive messages to AWS SQS message queue (standard type) but when I create a FIFO queue and try to send a message I receive an exception which is saying I have to set a non-empty Message group Id.

I found example of this in java at AWS documentation :

```
**// Send a message

SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest(myQueueUrl, "This is my message text.");
*// You must provide a non-empty MessageGroupId when sending messages to a FIFO queue
sendMessageRequest.setMessageGroupId("messageGroup1");*
```

But when I use the AWS.SQS package in c# I cannot find any properties or method which I can set the Message group Id.

this is the code

```
SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest();
sendMessageRequest.QueueUrl = myQueueUrl; //URL from initial queue creation
sendMessageRequest.MessageBody = "This is my message text.";
sqs.SendMessage(sendMessageRequest);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue, turned out I needed to install the AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.SQS packages and remove the base AWSSDK package I originally had.

Answer (score 1):

Well Actually there is a MessageGroupId property in SendMessageRequest. I could not find it because I was searching for it in the live example of the Awssdk.SQS and i thought they have the latest version but their example is not using the latest version so I could not found it. I installed the last version and then it start to work.

Answer (score 1):

Update the aws sdk version. You are using an old version.